# Markdown mode not working for .md files, python mode activated instead

Tags: linux, emacs, markdown

I have been trying to install `markdown-mode` for emacs in linux mint (ubuntu) using several of the methods provided. I have tried:

- installing the `emacs-goodies-el' and the 'elpa-markdown' packages in ubuntu
- Installing it using melpa package manager
- adding the following code to load the mode using the `use-package` package, by adding the following to my .emacs file:

```
(use-package markdown-mode
             :ensure t
             :commands (markdown-mode gfm-mode)
             :mode (("README\\\\.md\\\\'" . gfm-mode)
                    ("\\\\.md\\\\'" . markdown-mode)
                    ("\\\\.markdown\\\\'" . markdown-mode))
             :init
             (setq markdown-command "pandoc")
             (setq-default markdown-hide-markup t)
             )

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set-fill-column 100)))
```

I am however unable to get the markdown mode to load when opening a `.md` file. Instead, the Python mode opens. I wonder if this has to do with having some python code blocks in my file?

Also, might be useful, I have the following regarding python in my .emacs file:

```
;; Python Mode                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
(add-to-list                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 'auto-mode-alist                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 '(".py" . python-mode))     

(package-initialize)                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
(elpy-enable)                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
(elpy-use-ipython)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython3"                                                                                                                                                                                                
      python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt --pprint")                                                                                                                                                                          

(eval-after-load "elpy"                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  '(progn                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     (define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-r") 'elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer)))                                                                                                                                                      

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook                                                                                                                                                                                                              
          (lambda ()                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)))
```

At this point, I am a bit lost, does anyone have a clue why the markdown mode is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably too many escapes.  Try e.g. `("README\\.md\\'" . gfm-mode)`.

In your python `auto-mode-alist` config, your regexp is too general, due to lack of escapes; it matches any file name with `py` preceded by at least one char.  Try `("\\.py\\'" . python-mode)` (matching the literal string `.py` only at the end of the name).  I don't know why you even need that, because python-mode should set that up by default.